# How to find an element by style attribute?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am having trouble retrieving elements by style attribute.
I have a `ul` with several `li` elements and I would like to find the one with the style atribute having a value `display:list-item`. I have tried to approach this in several ways, including the following, but I keep getting an empty object. I have no problem with a title attribute. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
$('li[style*=display:list-item]')
```

HTML:

```html
<ul class="bjqs" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;">
    <li class="bjqs-slide" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; display: list-item;">
```

Comment: this seems like a bad idea. are you sure it is necessary? why can't you just get `.bjqs-slide`?

Comment: I have several .bjqs-slide li elements and I want to do something with the one that has this attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems:

1. In your HTML there is a space between "display:" and "list-item".
2. Your selector needs to be wrapped with quotations `""`.

Simply change your selector to include this space and wrap it in quotes:

```
$('li[style*="display: list-item"]')
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cLs5E/).

Comment: I also noticed that I was searching for this element before it was created by a plug-in, which I believe compounded my problem. When I included the white space as you suggested and moved it down a few lines, success. Thanks.

Comment: What if the `list-item` is a variable?

Answer (score 9):

Your selector is white-space sensitive, given that you have white-space in the attribute, you'll need that in your selector as well:

```
$('li[style*="display: list-item"]')
```

The easiest way, which reduces the problems of precisely matching a string, if you're filtering elements according to a particular CSS property, is to *use* `filter()`:

```
$('li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('display') === 'list-item';
});
```

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).